# Could anyone give me a scientific explanation of how a planet/creatures would have purple-ish hue?

Tags: planets, civilization, colors

so this is related to a different planet/civilization me and my friend have in mind.

The civilization is an intelligent life living far from earth, but what I have been thinking of is making the creatures and the planet itself have more of a purple/dark hue, the planet has vegetation, thick and big tress along with big sources of water.

I was thinking that the purple hue was caused by the sun of that planet having different rays then our sun, but I wonder if anyone could give me a more scientific explanation for the purple/dark hue, also would this planet even work out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Ultraviolet Spectrum**

[image: The sk]

The light that reaches the surface is purple due to atmospheric stuff. See answers to [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/17815/14322). The planet is also very hot because there is a lot of purple light. The animals are colored purple to reflect most of the visible light and not overheat. Their real colorings are in a band invisible to human eyes.

Comment: Do you think humans would be able to visit such a planet? Or do you think the suns rays would be too dangerous

Comment: @SaBeus They can always wear radiation suits.

Comment: Also would theese creatures also have the same problem if they visited earth?

Comment: @SaBeus I imagine they would be fine moving from their high-radiation planet to the low-radiation Earth.